# Meaning of "select c." in SQL

Tags: select, proc-sql

if, in proc sql in SAS I create a table and write:

```
<<
proc sql;

create table work.mytabbi as

select c.*
 ,o.dldl
 ,o.dldl;

quit;
>>
```

what does "c.*" mean in this program?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All the columns from the table called `c`

Answer (score 2):

c is the alias for a table used in the join and .* means all columns of that table.
Your query selects all columns of table c and other columns from table o